# maven-war-plugin upgrade to java 21

Tags: java, maven, war, java-21

We're using today

org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 which is working with java 11
which version do I  need so it will work for java 21 ?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project landingzone: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
```

Comment: You are using a 14 year old plugin (maven-war-plugin). Try upgrading it to a recent version (and compiler plugin as well). See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin

Comment: Best reference to be up-to-date with plugins: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the version of war plugin

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
```